# Haskell List of List problem

Tags: list, haskell

Im trying to change a particular particular list in a list of lists, Ive already defined the function which changes the list. But im not sure how to go about implementing this function into another function which changes that part of the list in a list of lists

The function im trying to define is in the form [[a]] -> a -> [[a]]
where a defines the part in the list of lists in trying to change

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Show us what you've got. Explain *as clearly as you can* what you're trying to do, and preferably why. Oh, and if this is homework please say so.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
map (map yourchangeFunction) yourdata
```

if I understand your question correctly.